# Many files are visible from Android but not visible from USB

Tags: usb, file-system, file-management

I was finding many times that many files are visible from within Android itself, but not visible from USB.

Latest example is OSMTracker files.

Here is the folder visible from Android itself:

[image]

And here is the same file as visible via USB:

[image]

I.e. there are 3 extra folders visible from inside.

How to fix this?

I would like to see all files from USB.

Comment: Settings-> Apps -> all apps -> find External Storage and clear cache.
Reboot, try again from [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/community/threads/cant-see-files-on-computer-solved.26777/)

Comment: Google source productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/Nexus/6lMKqYYXpXw

Comment: @beeshyams Since I'm also interested in and troubled by the question, I tried your tips, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to remedy the issue. For example, WeChat generates EXT_STORAGE/tencent/MicroMsg/downloads but it's invisible before and after doing what you posted.

Comment: @Dims If a reboot is out of the question (e.g. small/few files), consider moving the files to another place with a file explorer before finding it with PC - anywhere should do.